# How to edit InfoPath form from SharePoint Designer when it only returns an error message

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, error, custom-form, external-list

I'm trying to edit an InfoPath form for an external list from SharePoint Designer. After clicking on the "Design Forms in InfoPath" button I get the following error:
"Object 'blablabla.rem' has been disconnected or does not exist at the server."

[image: Error message screenshot]

I have to customize the edit form for 12 external lists and I have this message for 10 of them. I tried deleting and creating them again to no avail. I can view and edit the data of all of them through the standard view/edit forms in SP.

What have I done wrong ? What can I do about it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by myself. Actually it was related to my other [issue](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31718/what-is-the-permission-associated-with-form-design-in-infopath) which required that I use a farm admin credential to start SharePoint Designer and InfoPath to be able to create my forms. It seems that SPD and IP were started too long ago so I only had to restart them to make the error disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem after deleting the forms and trying to start over. Simply restarting SPD cleared the error and let me recreate the forms. Thank you!